# Displacement Map Filter in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing

I'm curious to know how one can implement the [effect demonstrated here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121228184436/http://www.somewhere-lefilm.com/) using OpenCV. I think it's some sort of displacement map filter but I'm not 100% sure.

After that page has fully loaded, move the mouse around to see the background image move (it's the effect I'm looking for).

Is it possible? How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's been almost 2 years since I've asked this question and I think it's time to answer it: the source code that implements this filter using OpenCV can be found in my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvDisplacementMapFilter).

The implementation is based on the documentation of [Adobe Flash DisplacementMapFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/DisplacementMapFilter.html).

There's another tutorial I recommend people to read: [Psyark’s DisplacementMapFilter Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140415062525/http://nodename.com/blog/2006/01/16/psyarks-displacementmapfilter-tutorial/). It's old but accurate.

The result:

[image: Output]

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks for getting back to it after so many years. It's 2017 and it's still amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, I don't know what they are using on this page. But you can get a similar effect using [Parallax Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_mapping) applied to a flat surface. In this case there is no occlusion, which makes it faster.

There is a shader implementation in [this thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/387447-parallax-mapping/) which should be easy enough to translate to a kernel.

[Here](http://www.scalari.net/2008/04/22/generating-stereoscopic-images-with-parallax-occlusion-mapping/) is another link that uses this technique for photos.

Comment: Hi! I just answered this question and I though you might be interested in taking a look at my results. Have a nice day!