# Video processing and filtering libraries

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, marvin-framework

I'm trying to decide which library to choose in order to create app that can
filters a video, for example beautify or clarity.

During my search I came across 2 candidates: OpenCv and FFmpeg, and I found a complete framework only for FFmpeg(so +1 for this).

I couldn't found a complete comparision between the two so if someone has tried them and can post the answer it would be really helpful.

Edit:

Another candidate is Marvin framework(Java project) for Android - https://code.google.com/p/android-image-filtering/

Comment: Hi, i am very interested in your achievements in this field. You very help me, if you contact with me whoose.daddy@gmail.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OpenCV** is a framework for Computer Vision and it's very limited for what you need because it requires you to write most of the cool filters yourself. **Nevertheless**, it provides a few techniques to blur images, change contrast, convert to grayscale, flip, crop, threshold, erode, dilate, resize, rotate, isolate colors, composite, and few other things. Just so you have an idea of how to implement filters, I recently implemented a [Displacement Map Filter using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673435/176769).

[**FFmpeg** has a few](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Filters) [filters as well](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Filters), but it's meant to be a cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video, which means it doesn't really offer many filter effects.

**Nevertheless, both APIs can read video (files and stream from camera) on Android and provide access to the video frames so you can execute your custom filters.**

I believe the technology that can really help you bring a large collection of filters to your application is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). Note that ImageMagick doesn't handle videos, so you can use Android's native API, OpenCV or FFmpeg for this part. [Here are a few examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/examples.php) of what you can do with an image using ImageMagick from the command line, a program interface, or script:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment, by the way - I decided not to use any of the because that FFmpeg uses GPL licence, and also OpenCV since it uses FFmpeg for video processing.

Answer (score 1):

there is a very useful OpenGL ES 2.0 library for video processing with many filters for ios

[GPUImage for Ios](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

the android wrapper is here :
[GPUImage Wrapper for Android](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage)

The GPUImage framework is a BSD-licensed iOS library that lets you apply GPU-accelerated filters and other effects to images, live camera video, and movies. In comparison to Core Image (part of iOS 5.0), GPUImage allows you to write your own custom filters, supports deployment to iOS 4.0, and has a simpler interface. However, it currently lacks some of the more advanced features of Core Image, such as facial detection.

Comment: as of now, video support in android-gpuimage is flawed
https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/issues/20
https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/issues/29