# Video editing API in Android

Tags: android, video, video-processing

Does Android have built-in abilities to do video editing? If so, where?

I need to get two MP4 videos, and generate one with a nice transition between the videos. Right now, I am sending everything to the server. However, I would love to be able to do it straight on the device. I also need to apply some basic effects to the video.

So, does Android have an API for this? If not, what tools/libraries/frameworks are available? And is the gap being covered?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619087/video-processing-and-filtering-libraries

Comment: Well is it just FFMpeg then really?

Comment: Yup. But you might also want to read: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

Comment: Can you add all that as an answer so that  I can accept it?

Comment: This is a really good question with a really good answer. Please leave it alone. Upvote this comment if you agree.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For video editing the library would be FFmpeg as referenced in other questions like: [Video processing and filtering libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619087/video-processing-and-filtering-libraries)

However Android has been improving its framework MediaCodec. It may help to read:
http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/
and the latest documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

And of course don't forget to take a look at the Media related Google Samples in github:
https://github.com/googlesamples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=media

**2019-11 Edit**:

Android Samples moved here:
https://github.com/android?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=media&type=&language=

Additionally if you can support a min SDK API level of 21 and only use [supported Android media codec profiles](https://source.android.com/compatibility/5.0/android-5.0-cdd) *so camera okay but random video off internet perhaps not* there are third-party libraries like [MasayukiSuda's Mp4Composer-android](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android) which might work for your use case.