# how to set effect on video in android programmatically?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have video which is save in sdcard, now i want to apply the effect like black and white and etc. it's functionality like editing in video which is already in photo editor or video editor applications.

now i want to that functionality in android programmatically? when user choose black and white color in option then it should be response very quickly and change the effect of our video and save it sdcard.

i have find some solution for this like,

```
https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects
```

but it has not save functionality of video and if i go through in 
"FFMPEG" library then it is not responding very quickly?

how can i change the effect of video and save this video in sdcard?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html) link have a lot of information regarding FFmpeg and i have used in alot of projects  use their source and ask your question on this forum regarding ffmpeg  you will surely get your answers ASAP

and this is the command for greyscale effect on your video black & White filter (Gray Scale):

commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -vf hue=s=0 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097152 -s 320x240 -r 30 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4";

Comment: :- is it respond quickly? because when i apply the command then it will take a time and i don't want to that.

Comment: nops buddy it will surely take a lil time coz its about video processing all command are called in asynchtask u cant even call them on main thread coz it might cost your layout to get stuck. :)

Comment: :- thank you brother.. how can i get more effects? i mean i want to use many effects in video.if my question is acceptable then plz up vote my question.

Comment: https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage well u can check this open source its implementing live camera effects. Dig out the logic from this source u might get what u want else u may ask questions on that forum Eli Hasson owner of this ffmeg wrapper will surely help you

Comment: read that given link and also read the comments or say faq on that page u never know u mught get what you want

Comment: :- Thank you , if my question is acceptable then plz up vote my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111437/discussion-between-mayank-sugandhi-and-adeel-turk).

Comment: Can you please give me a FFMPEG command for apply the color filter on the video using hax color code.

Comment: @PatelHiren bro u can use acv file for that its created in photoshop 
This is the detail of using acv file provided in given link above 


You can create some effects using Photoshop curves operation (Image, Adjustments, Curves (CNTL + M)), export the curves acv file, and apply it using this command:

String[]
complexCommand={"ffmpeg","-y","-i","/storage/emulated/0/vk2/in.mp4","-strict","experimental","-vf","curves=psfile=/storage/emulated/0/videokit/sepia.acv","-b","2097k","-vcodec","mpeg4","-ab","48000","-ac","2","-ar","22050","/storage/emulated/0/videokit/out.mp4"}

Comment: @PatelHiren  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619087/video-processing-and-filtering-libraries

Comment: @Adeel Turk Can you please contact me on skype: hirenkapuria